# Play back Bluetooth audio Streaming using Gstreamer

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer

I have started audio streaming from my Android Phone. I am able to play it in my laptop using pulse audio module loop back. But I wanted to play it using gstreamer. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the stream on the phone? How do you play it on the laptop (loop back from what source)?

A general starting point for gstreamer is gst-launch playbin2 uri="...". The first thing on the URI is the protocol (e.g. rtsp:// or http://) then your phones IP address, then the location of the stream (if needed).